# Merging feature representations of two different Networks using Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras

A simple hint is appreciated. 
How can we fuse the feature representations output from 2 different networks using Keras?

More explanation: 
The model consists of a CNN and Gated RNN. [The feature representations output from the networks are fused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z5ak.png) and fed to a standard softmax regression classifier.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a merge layer ([see doc here](https://keras.io/layers/core/))

The mode to chose is up to you, it might be a sum, a concatenation or a custom merge. 
If they are different features, I would recommend you to concatenate them and then use a Dense layer with softmax activation for your classification prediction.

Take care of using the right merge layer : `Merge` is used in sequential models (merging 2 layers) and `merge` is to merge tensors (using the functionnal API)

I hope this helps